# How can I make an assembly shift code?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am using SIM-PL assembler (MIPS instruction) and trying to make this assembly code. I need to shift the register value with 1, but when it comes to the last bit it has to 'restart' and add the value to the first bits. I have no clue how to even start this. Can anyone help me?

```
pattern = 110
Register value = 00......00000110 
Register value = 00......00001100
Register value = 00......00011000
....
Register value = 11......00000000
Register value = 10......00000001
Register value = 00......00000011
....
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an assembly shift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451987/what-is-an-assembly-shift)

Answer (score 0):

That's called a *rotate*. Since mips has no rotate, you can simply break it down into `(x >> 31) | (x << 1)`. Nothing magical there, I trust you have no problem translating this into assembly.

Comment: Just to be pedantic here: MIPS introduced the rotate instructions in the MIPS32r2 ISA which was released in 2002. However teaching tools like SPIM are mostly stuck on older versions of the ISA.

Answer (score -1):

Shifts do fill the "new" incoming bits with zero or 1, depending on the type of shift.

What you're describing is known as a rotate instruction. The rotate instructions push the bits leaving one end of the register into the incoming bits at the opposite end of the register.

rol for left rotate, ror for right rotate.

Most MIPS assemblers implement rotates for you, but the MIPS chip itself doesn't have a built in rotate instruction.